# How do i make my command return if a bot is mentioned?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, quick.db

This is the start of my command. I tried `if(member === bot) return message.channel.send("You can't rob bots")`
But it didnt work, any help would be appreciated

```
client.on('message', async message => {
  if(message.content.startsWith("$$rob")) {
const member = message.mentions.members.first()
if(!member) return message.channel.send("You need to mention a user to rob them")
```

Comment: `member.id === bot.id` may be better, as there could be two different object instances referencing the same member.

Answer (score 0):

`member === bot` is not the right way to check if a member is a bot. Remember, the `===` sign checks if the variables on the two sides of it are equal (in the case of triple equals, also checks if they are of the same type). `bot` is not a variable that you have declared, so this isnt how you do it.

Instead, check the `user` property of the member, which is the user behind the member object. Checking the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.2.0/class/User?scrollTo=bot) you'll find that the user has a boolean property called `bot` which tells if you if it is a bot or not. Thus the right way to check if the member is a bot is by:

```
if(member.user.bot === true) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Or of course,  simplified:

```
if(member.user.bot) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if(member.user.bot) {
    return message.channel.send("You can't rob bots")
}
```